# How can I get the creation timestamp of a file which is in a folder ? [python] [csv]

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, timestamp, export-to-csv

I want to get only one creation timestamp of any file in a folder because they all were created at the same time. When I use this code below, it only shows the timestamp of the folder but not the file. There are many folder with many files and the folder were created newer dates.

```
c_time = os.path.getctime(path)
dt_c = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(c_time)
```

Comment: Is `path` the abs path to your folder?

Comment: @hellbreak yes, path is the main folder.. in the main folder are sub folders and in the sub folders are files. I want to get the creation timestamp of one of the files and list in CSV. If I use the code above I only get the creation timestamp of the sub folder and not the files

Comment: have you tried to set the path to your file? like `/home/hellbreak/Documents/test.txt` ?

Answer (score 2):

`os.path.getctime()` method in Python is used to get the system’s `ctime` of the specified path
I guess you did right. `test.txt` Is on my current folder

```
import os
import datetime
path = 'test.txt'
c_time = os.path.getctime('test.txt')
dt_c = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(c_time)
print(dt_c)
```

Output:

```
2022-09-16 10:28:29.922116
```

If you want to find when your file was last modified, you can use  `os.path.getmtime()`

```
import os
import datetime
m_time = os.path.getmtime(path)
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(m_time)
print('Modified on:', dt)
```

Output:

```
Modified on: 2022-09-16 10:38:58.934354
```

Edited to reflect the comments
If you want to get the timestamp of all the files in a folder, you have to list all of them first. You can do it with the help of `os.listdir()`
The do something like this

```
dir_list = os.listdir(yourpathhere)
for f in dir_list[1:]:
    print("filename {}".format(f))
    c_time = os.path.getctime(f)
    dt_c = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(c_time)
    print("Creation date {}".format(dt_c))
    m_time = os.path.getmtime(path)
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(m_time)
    print('Modified on {}'.format(dt))
```

Output:

```
2022-09-16 10:38:58.934354
Modified on: 2022-09-16 10:38:58.934354
filename test.txt
Creation date 2022-09-16 10:38:58.934354
Modified on 2022-09-16 10:38:58.934354
filename test_2.py
Creation date 2022-09-16 11:02:29.505548
Modified on 2022-09-16 10:38:58.934354
```

Comment: Ive tried both and both show only the timestamp of the folder and not the files. the files in the folder has different names thats why I cant take a path name like test.txt

Comment: So I guess you should first get a list of the files in your dir and then get the timestamp of each of them

Comment: @Volcano, I edited the code above to reflect your comment.

Comment: @Volcano The code above is an example.  If you need to process several folders with several files, you can adapt it by listing and looping through the folders you need. anyway, Can you share a little bit of your code? I guess it would help to understand your case better.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import os
    import platform

from datetime import datetime, timezone

def creation_date(path_to_file):
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
       return os.path.getctime(path_to_file)
    else:
       stat = os.stat(path_to_file)
       try:
          # return stat.st_birthtime
          return datetime.fromtimestamp(stat.st_birthtime, tz=timezone.utc)
       except AttributeError:           
          # return stat.st_mtime
          return datetime.fromtimestamp(stat.st_mtime, tz=timezone.utc)


date_creation = creation_date('/home/henro/Documents/help/app/main.py')

print (date_creation)
output:
2022-09-16 08:44:18.115245+00:0
```

change the path_file to yours

Comment: thanks for your answer. Ive tried your code. it shows me the Unix timestamp from the folder but not the files inside the folder. Any ideas on how I can get the timestamp from one of the files in the folder?

Comment: if path_to_file is assign only to folder, so in that function you need to add code in to the folder.